# Sorting list of words according to list of characters in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have:

```
List<String> alphabet; (contains 26 unique characters as elements, for example 
qwertyuiosapdfghjklzcxvbnm)

List<String> wordsToArrange; contains words as elements, for example: 

 - apple 
 - stream
 - posthouse
 - sea
 - seed
```

I need to arrange the words according to the alphabet i have made.

My approach at the moment is with for cycles.

```
alphabet(i) compare it with all the words charAt(0)
if only 1 is found i put it to a new list arrangedList 

but if 2 is found i go alphabet(i+1) till the letter is found and now i can put them in a right order to arrangedList....

then move back to alphabet(i+1) till alphabet(26) and now all should be arranged correctly...
```

I have wrote some base for this code but i wanted to ask what would be other approaches before i start the serious "for cyclying".

Thanks!

Follow-up
[Changing specific characters in List of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690638/changing-specific-characters-in-list-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Map each letter in your words to be sorted to the "inverse" of your alphabet. For instance:

   - `'a'` is the 11-th letter of that string, so map it to `'k'`
   - `'b'` is the 24-th letter of that string, so map it to `'x'`
   - etc.
2. Sort the list using `Collections.sort`
3. Map each letter in the sorted words back to their original letter, e.g. `'k' -> 'a'; 'x' -> 'b'`.

Comment: If i understand it correctly then it would only work for "qwertyuiosapdfghjklzcxvbnm" but i need it to work for every combination edit: but if i now think more deeply about it then this would work if use alphabet as indexes and map to letters

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry for that, English is my second languange, yes this would work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Java 8's filter and streams to filter out the ones beginning with a certain character.. Then I'd sort the results. If it needs to be in a single array, then combine the results.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 * Created by Brandon on 2016-04-17.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] array = new String[]{"apple", "stream", "posthouse", "sea", "seed"};
        //char[] indices = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        char[] indices2 = new char[]{'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm'};

        for (char key : indices2) {
            String[] result = Arrays.stream(array).filter(value -> value.charAt(0) == key).toArray(length -> new String[length]);

            if (result.length > 0) {
                Arrays.sort(result);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If using `indices`, then the result is:

```
[apple]
[posthouse]
[sea, seed, stream]
```

If using `indices2`, then the result is:

```
[posthouse]
[apple]
[sea, seed, stream]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping the String in a new Class that implements comparable?

May be some edge case bugs that i have not tested.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CompString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ComparableString> list = new ArrayList<ComparableString>();

        list.add(new ComparableString("apple"));
        list.add(new ComparableString("stream"));
        list.add(new ComparableString("posthouse"));
        list.add(new ComparableString("sea"));
        list.add(new ComparableString("seed"));

        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println(list);
    }

}

class ComparableString implements Comparable<ComparableString> {

    String str;
    static String sortOrder = "qwertyuiosapdfghjklzcxvbnm";

    public ComparableString(String string) {
        str = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableString other) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(this.str.length(), other.str.length()); i++) {
            int thisOrder = ComparableString.sortOrder.indexOf(this.str.charAt(i));
            int thatOrder = ComparableString.sortOrder.indexOf(other.str.charAt(i));

            int order = thisOrder - thatOrder;
            if (order != 0) {
                return order;
            }

        }

        if (this.str.length() > other.str.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.str.length() < other.str.length()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```