# Changing specific characters in List of Strings in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Backstory:

```
List<String> alphabet; // (contains 26 unique characters as elements, for example 
    // qwertyuiosapdfghjklzcxvbnm)

List<String> wordsToArrange; // contains words as elements, for example: 

 - apple 
 - stream
 - posthouse
 - sea
 - seed
```

I need to arrange the words according to the alphabet I have made.

I was doing huge and many for loops before, but [I got an idea from an answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36682270/3788176) to map it like:

```
alphabet(0) --> "a";
alphabet(1) --> "b";
.................
alphabet(25) --> "z";
```

So the words would change, apple would become apple ---> kjjsc
Then I could use `collection.sort` and to a new list, and then convert the words back to normal..

```
for(int i = 0; i < wordsToArrange.size(); i++){

List<String> charArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordsToArrange.get(i).split("")));

int arraySize = wordsToArrange.get(i).length();

Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(0), "a");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(1), "b");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(2), "c");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(3), "d");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(4), "e");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(5), "f");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(6), "g");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(7), "h");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(8), "i");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(9), "j");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(10), "k");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(11), "l");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(12), "m");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(13), "n");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(14), "o");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(15), "p");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(16), "q");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(17), "r");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(18), "s");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(19), "t");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(20), "u");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(21), "v");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(22), "w");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(23), "x");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(24), "y");
Collections.replaceAll(charArray, alphabet.get(25), "z");

StringBuilder listString = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : charArray)
    listString.append(s+"");
System.out.println(listString);
```

This seems to overwrite all the characters so the output is:

```
rqqsw
sezwrz
qisepiosw
swr
swwz
```

My brain is quite foggy today and I think I could push this way to the end till I have some kind of solution, but this does not seem like the efficient way to do it. Any ideas?

At the moment I take a word from a list, make it into a char array so I could change very character separately, then put the new char array back to string, and then I would replace it in the list with a new word (or make a new list). After I have gone through all the words I would have a list. I would use `collection.sort` on it and then convert back to normal words, but now in correct order.

My first question: 
[Sorting list of words according to list of characters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682159/sorting-list-of-words-according-to-list-of-characters-in-java/36682471#36682471)

Comment: "but i got idea from stackoverflow" You should add a link to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the characters you are replacing them with is also characters you will replace later.

The simplest approach is to change the characters in a single pass.

```
public static String encode(String input, String dict) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
        int index = dict.indexOf(ch); // look for the character
        if (index >= 0)
           sb.append((char) ('a' + index)) // use the matching char instead
        else
           sb.append(ch); // otherwise copy untranslated.
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```